# How to select from a model all elements that have no relation to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, associations, scopes

Sorry for the vague title.
I have 3 tables: User, Place and PlaceOwner.
I want to write a scope in the "PlaceOwner" model to get all the "Places" that don't have an owner.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :place_owner
end
```

```
class PlaceOwner < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place

  #scope :places_without_owner, -> {}
```

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :place_owners
end
```

I tried checking for association in the rails console for each element and it worked. But I don't know how to implement this at scope. I've seen people solve similar problems by writing SQL but I don't have the knowledge to write it that way. I understand that I need to check all IDs from Place to see if they are in the PlaceOwner table or not. But I can't implement it.

**For example:**

There are 3 records in the "Place" table: *House13, House14, House15*.

There are 2 records in the "PlaceOwner" table: *House13 - User1*, *House 14 - User2*

I want to get *House15*

I hope I explained clearly what I'm trying to do. Please help or at least tell me where to go. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain#missing`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing) method which was introduced in Ruby on Rails 6.1:

```
Place.where.missing(:place_owners)
```

Quote from the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing):

> `missing(*associations)`
>
> Returns a new relation with left outer joins and where clause to identify missing relations.
>
> For example, posts that are missing a related author:
>
> ```
> Post.where.missing(:author)
> # SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
> # LEFT OUTER JOIN "authors" ON "authors"."id" = "posts"."author_id"
> # WHERE "authors"."id" IS NULL
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In older versions:

```
Place.includes(:place_owners).where(place_owners: { id: nil })
Place.left_joins(:place_owners).where(place_owners: { id: nil })
```

Another interesting option is using `EXISTS`. Very often such queries have better performance, but unfortunately rails haven't such feature yet (see discussions [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21438) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40719))

```
Place.where_not_exists(:place_owners)
Place.where_assoc_not_exists(:place_owners)
```

To use these methods you need to use [`where_exists`](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) or [`activerecord_where_assoc`](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc) gem